# Webjars- Spring boot

Tags: spring, zurb-foundation, webjars

I aaded webjar(foundation 6.3.1) via Maven and how i can figure out the link to resource? I mean that I cannot see folder with generated resource like css, js etc. in Intellij output folder(target) so how i know which is valid path? 
I found valid path to bootstrap as example and i tested it

```
/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

it works but if i have another webjars i have to guess what is path to it?!

[Output directory content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMnEz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, maybe it will be usefull for others. In html code you will get prompts from IDE when start with webjars. Example below

[IDE prompts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiXBP.png)